# Electron: how to execute AngularJS in Electron without CSRF protection?

Tags: angularjs, csrf, electron, httpserver

Recently I started working on my first electron app and and bumped into a problem, hope someone may be able to help me out.

I would like to use Electron to quickly create a cool looking app by using a Admin Backend AngluarJS HTML theme.

The AngluarJS theme works fine from a http:// source but not when I load the theme from a local drive like the C:\ drive, it breaks the theme because (I think) of CSRF protection policies in chrome.

Now I googled my ass off but I can't find a good solution. I thought that running a http-server in electron might be a solution so I tried the npm http-server package. Problem with this approach is that the nodejs code is not working anymore in this case beceause the http-server will only proces static files.

Is there maybe another solution?

Thanks for thinking with me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electron has no problem running an AngularJs app.
I have built a few Electron apps using Angular with no CSRF problems.

One way to get around this is to create a simple server running inside electron, like shown below:

```
// <YOUR-ENTRY-FILE>.js

app.on('ready', function() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600
    });

    var server = http.createServer(requestHandler).listen(9527);

    mainWindow.loadUrl('http://localhost:9527/index.html');
    mainWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', function() {
        mainWindow.setTitle(app.getName());
    });
    mainWindow.on('closed', function() {
        mainWindow = null;
        server.close();
    });
});

function requestHandler(req, res) {
    var
        file    = req.url == '/' ? '/index.html' : req.url,
        root    = __dirname + '/www',
        page404 = root + '/404.html';

    getFile((root + file), res, page404);
};

function getFile(filePath, res, page404) {

    fs.exists(filePath, function(exists) {
        if(exists) {
            fs.readFile(filePath, function(err, contents) {
                if(!err) {
                    res.end(contents);
                } else {
                    console.dir(err);
                }
            });
        } else {
            fs.readFile(page404, function(err, contents) {
                if(!err) {
                    res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
                    res.end(contents);
                } else {
                    console.dir(err);
                }
            });
        }
    });
};
```

There really should not be a need for you to do this, check your paths and have this as the last option.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I think this is indeed a little "dirty" but it is nice to have the option to run the app as http-server and use nodejs in electron. Thanks for the code example, it will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

quite late, but i found a solution to this, maybe this helps someone someday https://stackoverflow.com/a/60452312/1284216